# Paypal ExpressCheckout: setting what buyer sees in receipts and transactions

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am setting up Paypal ExpressCheckout 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout/

It's working fine (finally!), at least in Sandbox mode, but the receipt to my test buyer says "Receipt for Your Payment to test facilitator's Test Store"

I don't know what it will say in non-sandbox mode or where I can set the company name as it should appear in the receipt. I also find the format confusing:

"...your payment to some_user at some_store".

It should just be "... your payment to some_store", no?

Also, what will the buyer see in the transactions overview? I'm not seeing this at all in the sandbox view. (Transactions are empty. I can only see the payments under 'notifications'.)

```
data_dict =  {
    "USER":keys.PAYPAL_USER,
    "PWD":keys.PAYPAL_PWD,
    "SIGNATURE":keys.PAYPAL_SIGNATURE,
    "VERSION":"124",
    "METHOD":"DoExpressCheckoutPayment",
    "TOKEN":token,
    "PAYERID":payer_id,
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT":amount,
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE":"USD",
    "PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION" :"SALE"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message will be: Receipt for Your Payment to "The name of the company registered at Paypal". You can switch to live and test with a sample small payment.